# VS-Code extension - inspect file without saving it

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my extension I use CodeActionsProvider and HoverProvider.
This functionality works well when I open a file - it shows me the problems and the hovers.

However I want to apply CodeAction and Hover on open files:

1. User opens "abc.txt".
2. User changes something in "abc.txt" and save it.
3. My extension does its magic and creates some new hovers and problems. "abc.txt" is still open.
4. The new hovers and problems are presented to the user in "abc.txt" without reopenning the file. <-- How??

I managed to present the new hovers and problems by executing the save command: `workbench.action.files.save`. However, I couldn't find any way on how to do it without saving the file.

How can I trigger a file inspection without saving it?